# How to have display Android buttons in a user friendly way?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, layout

I have an application which needs **different filters** which are implemented by the click of a **button** and now I am out of space on the screen because I still have `Button7-15` to implement and the **layout** of the application can be seen below in the picture:

[image]

As seen there is not enough space to display 15 buttons and not to say that it would look odd to display 15 buttons all together so how can I display 15 buttons on the screen in a user-friendly manner (eg. ScrollDown for more buttons) and if someone has some example code for it then I would deeply appreciate it.

For people who would like to see the `.xml` file of the layout, here is the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/filter_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filter1_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_white_red_transluscent"
        android:text="@string/filter1_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filter2_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_white_red_transluscent"
        android:text="@string/filter2_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        ....and so on for the rest of the buttons

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/filter_image_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/filter_linear_layout" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). There are plenty of examples available on the internet.

- [ScrollView](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#gridlayout_scrollview)
- [Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNX996ZZ2CI)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a fancy ui widget of your choice that e.g. hides when needed, or provides an iconic sidebar with the menu items instead of buttons. Have look at [Androidviews.com](http://www.androidviews.net/):

RibbonMenu: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/ribbonmenu/
SwipeListView: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/swipelistview/